Why uwsgi doesn't disable threads inside django application
Uwsgi docs says, that threads inside an application are turned off until you haven't explicitly turned them on.
For me, it works not like that.
I have checked it through a simple view in django.
uwsgi run params:
   - uwsgi
      - --socket=0.0.0.0:8081
      - --module=conf.shop.wsgi
      - --buffer-size=65535
      - --py-autoreload=1
      - --lazy
      - --lazy-apps
      - --vacuum

When uwsgi starts, it writes:

*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***

View code:
from threading import Thread

def view():
    def foo(time_sleep, number: int):
        time.sleep(time_sleep)
        return number
    
    results = {}
    threads = []
    for i in range(8):
        thread = Thread(
            target=foo,
            kwargs={'time_sleep': 1, 'number': i},
            name=f'task {i}',
        )

        threads.append(thread)
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]
    performed_threads = [thread for thread in threads if thread.result is not None]
    for thread in performed_threads:
        results[thread.name] = thread.result
        
    return results

But this code works for 1s, not 8s.
I tried --strict and many other options, but didn't find why it works in that way.
How to turn them off, if it is possible?

You misunderstood the docs. Uwsgi does not disable threading completely, by default it does not use multiple threads per process to handle requests.
